# will a production app show before an early access app with the same name?

Tags: android, google-play

So I am in a weird situation. By chance another developer and me have chosen the same name for our app, both our releases are in early access mode and were released for testing only a month appart.
When searching on the play store google play will sometimes show his app and at other times it will show mine seemingly by chance.

My question is  is if the first app to be released propperly will be prefered  or if this will continue being governed by chance. I really want to avoid having to rename my app but having the other app appear  as the official result on google play can lead to confusion especially since we are both in the same country.

what are your thoughts on my situation